# how to change .toLocaleString() digits to english?

Tags: javascript

I try to change a date from Gregorian date to local date (Jalali). with this code:

```js
document.write(new Date().toLocaleString("fa-IR"))
```

and it returns:  ۱۴۰۱/۱۲/۲۲, ۱۱:۴۲:۰۰

But I need to be return output in English digits, like this:  1401/11/22, 11:42:00

Comment: I don't have experience with this kind of `locale`s, have you tried different variations of it? If you need English format, why using custom locale in the first place?

Comment: Use [locale calendar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/calendar) instead of locale date string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `toLocaleString` the first option is preferred for language, if you want to have an Gregorian date with English digits you should use [calendar option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options) such as

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString("en" , {calendar: 'persian'}));
```

Comment: *"...the first option is preferred for language"* Indeed. While you **can** specify the calendar in the first argument (`.toLocaleString("en-GB-u-ca-islamic")`), doing it as above is better.

Comment: That should probably be `persian` instead of `islamic`.